# How to sort only positive data in Pandas Series that contains negative and zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas series that have negative numbers, zeros and positives numbers. What is the simplest way to sort only the positive entries in descending order and return the top 10 from the sorted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.random.seed(123)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(-100,100,50))
s[s>0].sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
```

Output:

```
25    95
32    89
39    80
33    76
15    74
47    68
20    64
44    55
17    53
34    35
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Are you sure? :(

Comment: Thanks. I should have added that I want to sort only the positive numbers in a descending order out of the total population that have negative numbers and zeros.

Comment: @Liam using this sample dataset what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
#borrowing data from Scott Boston
print (s[s>0].nlargest(10))

25    95
32    89
39    80
33    76
15    74
47    68
20    64
44    55
17    53
34    35
dtype: int32
```